# How to extract multiple columns of data out of two different text files and format them correctly to be used in more code

Tags: python, arrays, text-files, multiple-columns

I am trying to extract multiple columns of data from two different text files. I am going to loop through those columns of data with additional code. How do I extract it, and format the data correctly so I can use it. There are probably 20 columns in one text file, and 15 columns in the other text file.

I have tried extract the data using genfromtext, but I get a weird format and mapping it doesn't help. I also can't use the extracted data in any additional loops or functions.

This is the code I was trying to use:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("Basecol_Basic_New_1.txt", unpack=True);
J_i2=data[0];
J_f2=data[1];
kH2=data[5:, :]

data = np.genfromtxt("Lamda_HeHCL.txt", unpack=True);
J_i1=data[1];
J_f1=data[2];
kHe=data[7:, :]
```

I also tried using this to format correctly, but it kept resulting in errors.

```
kHe = map(float, kHe)
kH2 = map(float, kH2)

kHe = np.array(kHe)
kH2 = np.array(kH2)

g = len(kH2)
```

However, once I have the columns of data, they are formatted differently than I am used to. They seem to be unusable.

I expect that the data will come out as multiple arrays `[1,2,3], [4,5,6]`. What I am currently getting is `[[5.678e-8 ....] [7.893e-10 ...]]`.
It isn't in the right format and all my attempts to put it in the right format result in a size-1 error or similar.

Comment: Can you provide: first few lines of the text files, code that lead you to get that incorrect answer? It's impossible to answer your question due to lack of information.

Comment: Yes, I can provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I'm assuming the data is separated by spaces. Then you can just read the file and format instead of using `np.genfromtext`

Edited for mapping float and column 5 to 10 inclusive (6 columns).

```
list=[]
with open ("Basecol_Basic_New_1.txt", 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        list.append(map(float,line.strip().split(' ')[4:10]))
```

Comment: How would I just take columns 5-10 using this code? Also, I am having a little trouble using map(float, list).

Comment: @Cosmoman edited answer for 5-10 columns inclusive and using map(float, list)

Comment: Thanks, I think I almost have it. I am just receiving a "cannot convert string to float" error. Any reason why that is?

Comment: It means at least one of your data has non-numerical value and cannot convert to float

Comment: Okay, thanks. It looks like my output when I do [4:10] is mostly '' and '1'. When I remove it does all the columns again. Maybe I'll just put it in excel and try reformatting it.

Comment: Just an update. For some reason, the split needed two spaces instead of one.